# Questions tagged 'android-beta-program'

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got an [android-beta-program](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-beta-program) tag (currently used by 6 questions) on our main side. How do we want to deal with that?

We've already discussed "nightly builds" in [Recommendation for questions pertaining to a problem specific to a nightly build of a ROM](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/16575), and I find this quite similar: Those questions including their answers have no value in the long run if they are about issues a user has with Beta software. And they would be off-topic anyway if the question deals with the beta program itself.

So how do we want to deal with a) that tag and b) questions using it?

Comment: "And they would be off-topic anyway if the question deals with the beta program itself." Why is that? Most of the questions with that tag seem OK to me.

Comment: @DanHulme because most of them don't fall into the category of "dealing with the beta program itself". Currently, there is no such question using that tag. An example of such would be "How can I enroll in the ABP?"

Comment: FYI, I removed the tag from 2 unrelated questions. I don't have opinion on this tag, since there's also [tag:development-preview] that I created long before.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks! That even raises the question if the two should be merged. I wouldn't raise that on SO (where it might be counted as different topics) – but for a user-oriented site, this might be seen different.

Answer (score 1):

The [android-beta-program](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-beta-program) has no tag-wiki yet. I propose to add one similar to that of our [development](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) tag:

> Development questions are off-topic. Do not ask them here.

For the tag in question, that would be:

> Questions dealing with the beta program are off-topic here. See the tag-wiki ("info" link) for details.

In the tag-wiki itself we then should explain that:

- questions dealing with (details pertaining) the beta-program are strictly off-topic
- questions dealing with beta-/pre-releases of (new) Android versions are not welcome because …

Details for the "because" part we could compile as extract from the post linked in the question.

The questions then should be dealt with accordingly (VTC off-topic for questions concerning the beta program as such – open for suggestions on other "beta issues", but I'd say declaring them OT as well: beta-testing belongs to the domain of development).