# Questions about issues in a nightly that were also present in a stable build

Tags: discussion, questions, question-appropriateness

Sometimes, there are issues that affects one or many nightlies, and that are carried over since a stable release, or even before it.

For example, I'm currently running a CM13 nightly build, and have a Wi-Fi issue that's present since the first CM13 nightly, and which affected even the one stable build that was rolled out some months ago.

Given that the issue never changed, and so it doesn't depend on a specific nightly, which policy should be applied? Should such a question be flagged? Closed? Would it be legitimate to ask it?

Comment: Mentioning clearly in the question that the problem is a legacy issue carried over from stable versions and not a specific behaviour of *only* nightly builds ought to prevent a) flagging / closure b) Make it legitimate.  My 2C. +1

Comment: @beeshyams Would you care to post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [requested by OP](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/questions-about-issues-in-a-nightly-that-were-also-present-in-a-stable-build?noredirect=1#comment6140_2209):

Mentioning clearly in the question ( possibly prefacing so that knee jerk closure flags are *not* triggered) with a text on lines of

> This question pertains to a problem that is a legacy issue carried over from stable versions and not a specific behaviour of nightly builds

This ought to prevent:

- Flagging / closure of the question being a [nightly related](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/131553)
- Make it legitimate.